# E-mail é enviado apenas para o último usuário confirmado/ativo

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Bom, é o seguinte.

Estava fazendo alguns testes de envio de Newsletter e me deparei com um problema.

A parte de cadastro/inserção do usuário tá feita, funcionando tudo certinho.

Porém, eu estava realizando o envio apenas para um e-mail, o meu no caso. Então resolvi inserir mais alguns para verificar como o sistema se sairia. Notei que ele, independente do e-mail (Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo..), envia apenas para o último cadastrado, ou seja, o último usuário que confirmou o cadastro através do e-mail de confirmação que é enviado para o e-mail do mesmo. Ao confirmar, o token e o status do usuário é trocado.

Bom, se não ficou claro é só perguntar.

Segue o código da página em questão:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    header("Location: home.php?action=ver-newsletter"); exit;
}
$id = $_GET['id'];
$select = "SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE id=:id";
$contagem = 1;
try{
    $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();
    $contar = $result->rowCount();
    if($contar>0){
        while($show = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $idNews = $show->id;    
            $titulo = $show->titulo;    
            $data = $show->data;    
            $imagem = $show->imagem;    
            $descricao = $show->descricao;  
        }
    }else{
        echo 
        '<div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Aviso!</strong>Não há Newsletter cadastrada com o id informado!
        </div>';
    }
}catch(PDOException $error){
echo $error;
}
$novoNome = $imagem;
//ATUALIZAR
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $titulo         = trim(strip_tags($_POST['titulo']));
    $data           = trim(strip_tags($_POST['data']));
    $descricao  = $_POST['descricao'];
    if(!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
        //INFO IMAGEM
        $file           = $_FILES['img'];
        $numFile        = count(array_filter($file['name']));
        //PASTA
        $folder     = '../upload/newsletter/';
        //REQUISITOS
        $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
        $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
        //MENSAGENS
        $msg            = array();
        $errorMsg   = array(
            1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
            2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
            3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
            4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
        );
        if($numFile <= 0){
            /*echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Selecione uma imagem e tente novamente!
            </div>';*/
        }
        else if($numFile >=2){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Você ultrapassou o limite de upload. Selecione apenas 1 imagem!
            </div>';
        }else{
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
                $name   = $file['name'][$i];
                $type       = $file['type'][$i];
                $size       = $file['size'][$i];
                $error      = $file['error'][$i];
                $tmp        = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

                $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

                if($error != 0)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
                else if($size > $maxSize)
                $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
                else{
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){
                        //$msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";
                        $arquivo = "../upload/newsletter/".$imagem;
                        unlink($arquivo);
                    }else{
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";
                    }
                }
                foreach($msg as $pop)
                    //echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    else{
    $novoNome = $imagem;
    }

    $select = "SELECT * FROM usersnewsletter WHERE status = 1";
    try{
        $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
        $result->execute();
        $contar = $result->rowCount();
        if(!$contar>0){
            echo 
            '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <strong>Aviso!</strong>Não há usuários ativos!
            </div>';
        }else{
            while($show = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                $idUser     = $show->id;    
                $name       = $show->name;  
                $sobrenome  = $show->sobrenome; 
                $mail       = $show->mail;  
                $token      = $show->token; 
                $status     = $show->status;    

                require_once('envia-email/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

                $Email = new PHPMailer();
                $Email->SetLanguage("br");
                $Email->IsSMTP();
                $Email->SMTPAuth = true;
                $Email->Host = '';
                $Email->Port = ''; 
                $Email->Username = ''; 
                $Email->Password = '';                  
                $Email->IsHTML(true); 
                $Email->From = '';              
                $Email->FromName = utf8_decode('');
                $Email->AddReplyTo($mail, '');
                $Email->AddAddress($mail); 
                $Email->Subject =  utf8_decode ($titulo);
                $url    = 'http://www.#####.#####.br/newsletter/cancel.php?token='.$token;
                $Email->Body .= 
                utf8_decode 
                ('
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                            <head>
                                <style>
                                    table, th, td {
                                        border: 1px solid black;
                                        border-collapse: collapse;
                                    }
                                    th, td {
                                        padding: 5px;
                                        text-align: left;    
                                    }
                                    #logo{
                                        width: 250px;
                                        text-align: center;
                                        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                                        padding: 20px;
                                    }
                                    #titulo{
                                        width: 70%;
                                        padding: 1% 3%;
                                        text-align: center;
                                        border-top: 1px solid white;
                                        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                                        background: #009BD2;
                                    }
                                    h1{
                                    color: white;
                                    }
                                    #por{
                                        padding-left: 5%;
                                        border-top: 1px solid white;
                                        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                                    }
                                    #imgprinc{
                                        text-align: center;
                                        width: 100%;
                                        padding: 3% 5%;                                                 
                                        border-top: 1px solid white;
                                        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                                    }
                                    #conteudo{
                                        padding: 3% 5% 2%;
                                        text-align: justify;
                                    }
                                    #footer{
                                        background: #009BD2;
                                        color: white;
                                    }
                                </style>
                            </head>
                        <body>
                            <table style="width:100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;">    </th>
                                    <th style="width: 250px; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid white; padding: 20px;" id="logo">                                     
                                        <img id="logo" src="http://www.#####.#####.br/blog/admin/img/logonews.png">
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">   </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;">   </td>
                                    <td style="width: 70%; padding: 1% 3%; text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; background: #009BD2;" id="titulo">
                                        <h1 style=" background: #009BD2; color: white;">'.$titulo.'</h1>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">   </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;">    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-left: 5%; border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white;"  id="por">
                                        <small>                     
                                            '.$data.' '.date('H:i').'<br>                                               
                                            Por <strong>'.$nameLogged.'
                                        </small>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white;">    </td>
                                    <td style=" text-align: center; width: 100%; padding: 3% 5%; border-top: 1px solid white;   border-bottom: 1px solid white;"  id="imgprinc">
                                        <img src="http://www.#####.####.br/blog/upload/newsletter/'.$novoNome.'">
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">   </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white; ">   </td>
                                    <td style="padding: 3% 5% 2%; text-align: justify;" id="conteudo">
                                        '.$descricao.'
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">   </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-left: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid #009BD2;">    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; background: #009BD2; color:white; border: 1px solid #009BD2; padding: 15px 0">
                                        <small>     
                                            <strong>#####</strong>  #####
                                                <br>
                                                #####
                                                <br>                    
                                                #####
                                                <br>
                                                #####
                                                <br>
                                                Se não deseja mais recebe-los, 
                                                <strong>
                                                    <a style="color: white;" href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">
                                                        clique aqui.
                                                    </a>
                                            </strong>
                                        </small>
                                    </td>                                       
                                    <td style="border-top: 1px solid white; border-bottom: 1px solid white; border-right: 1px solid white;">   </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                ');
            }               
        }

        if(!$Email->Send()){        
            echo 
            '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>Erro!</strong> Houve um problema ao enviar o e-mail! para'.$mail.'
            </div>';
            echo "Erro: " . $Email->ErrorInfo;
        }else{
            echo 
            '<div class="alert alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>Sucesso!</strong> A Newsletter foi enviada! 
            </div>';
        }
    }catch(PDOException $error){
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: A instrução que envia email está fora do laço de repetição. Por isso envia somente para o úlltimo.